# What is the fastest and lightest way to send some task to background?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, handler

What is the less memory consuming and fastest (in respect of code lines and time of execution) way to do some task in the background thread?

I need to send many simple tasks to the background thread and I won't obviously use `AsyncTask` class for this. So is `handler` what I am looking for or there's a faster way?

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    infoMsg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
```

Comment: Why not AsyncTask? Or better AsyncTaskLoader? What are your "simple tasks"?

Comment: @MichałK One line commands like the one I wrote. Mostly setting visibility with time delay.

Comment: Then handler would be your best bet I suppose, but I have another idea, which may sound weird to you, but think about it. If it's only changing visibility, you can do it in the ui thread without problems. The only problem is the time delay. But you can use animation to do it and delay the animation by 1 sec. It would be by far the simplest solution and I also think it's pretty lightweight compared to handlers. Note: delaying animation doesn't freeze your ui thread

Comment: @MichałK Thanks. In this case you're absolutely right. upvote. What about theoretical question: Which back thread way is the lightest?

Comment: Don't know unfortunately. I can, however, tell you which is least problematic to use - Loader. It can be used for writing data as well, not only for loading and it's biggest advantage is that it has a built in mechanism to prevent memory leaks and problems with configuration change. And it nicely separates the logic of background thread. I use AsyncTaskLoaders nearly everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

handler is usually used for the UI thread in order to postpone something to be done in the future.
in your example , this solution would be perfect.

asynctask is used when you don't care for when and what should be the order of the tasks to do . asynctasks should not be used for too long operations (like a connection that keeps being alive till the end user stops it) . you cannot assume that at more than one asynctask are active (but one is ok to assume) .

for any other usage , i simply use a thread , but mostly the handler and the asynctask are enough.

Comment: thanks. great explanation. what does the last sentence mean "for any other usage , i simply use a thread"? which thread?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the handler is the fastest way at the moment of writing this post. In case a faster approach appears, I will change this question or mark other post as answer.